# ArgumentException: failed to convert parameters in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to change a material's color. This is the code I use:

```
public GameObject result;
Color color;
GameObject actualChangingObject;

public void OneOfTheGemsButton(GameObject objectThatChangesColor)
{
    changeColorMenu.SetActive(true);
    gemsMenu.SetActive(false);

    actualChangingObject = objectThatChangesColor;
}

public void OkButton()
{
    color = result.GetComponent<Image>().color;
    actualChangingObject.GetComponent<Material>().color = color;
    actualChangingObject = null;

    changeColorMenu.SetActive(false);
    gemsMenu.SetActive(true);
}
```

"result" is a UI image, which contains the color I want.
So by debugging I found that this:`color = result.GetComponent<Image>().color;` line of code doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: I tried changing  
`public GameObject result;` to `public Image result;`   and
`Color color;` to `Color32 color;`  
But they didn't work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put:
`Color color = new Color();`
instead of
`Color color;`